# about text file in vb.net

Tags: file-io, vb.net-2010

I create text file and would like to write some content to that file, but I am getting an error in the stream writer statement.

```
-------
 Dim fileLoc As String = "d:\sample1.txt"
    Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
    If (Not File.Exists(fileLoc)) Then
        fs = File.Create(fileLoc)
    Else
        File.Delete(fileLoc)
        fs = File.Create(fileLoc)
    End If
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileLoc)
   --------
   --------
   some thing

    ----------
    ----------
   sw.writeline(phone)

   ---------
   end using
```

The error I get is:

> The process cannot access the file 'd:\sample1.txt' because it is
>   being used by another process.

Comment: Do you have the file open somewhere else? Which line is the error on? Where you write to the file? Where you create the `StreamWriter`? Where you check if it exists?

Comment: getting error in stremwritter line .the file was created under d:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens since you are deleting the file and soon creating it. The delete process is going on so it would allow you create the file.

```
Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "\Log\log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
Dim s As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs)
s.Close()
fs.Close()$
```

Hope this code helps you.

Comment: instead of ""\Log\log.txt" am giving "d:\sample.txt". but am getting error in this line. like the give path format is not supported